# firebase friendlychat-web how to add data in new collection?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to add new collection in my firestore. I have changed following in my JS file.
    return firebase.firestore().collection('users').add({....
.i.e  changed to 'users' from 'messages'

but its not working.

Comment: The FriendlyChat codelab and sample app use the Firebase Realtime Database, and not Cloud Firestore. I highly recommend taking the entire codelab to get the best understanding of how it works: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-web/. If that doesn't help you solve the problem, create a minimal, complete, standalone reproduction of the problem. See [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for hints on how and why to do that.

Comment: is it not cloud firestore? pl see this https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-web/#7

Comment: It **is**. It looks like the codelab was updated to use Firestore and I missed that. Thanks for pointing that out. The second part of my comment still remains: without a minimal, complete example that reproduces the problem, it's hard to help (and future users won't be able to benefit from your learnings).

Answer (score 0):

Its the problem of rules. matching document name should be added in rules.